# Set LayoutParams Opacity

Tags: java, android, opacity, layoutparams

I have some code (android source), and Im trying to set Opacity of a `LayoutParam`

First, I've got this

```
mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            height,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TOUCHABLE_WHEN_WAKING
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
            // Setup statusbar transparency preference
             mOpacity != 100 ? PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT : PixelFormat.RGB_565);
```

Then I register a SettingsObserver, for reloading mOpacity, but if I set Opacity back to 100, it wont be `RGB_565`, as `LayoutParams` have defined `TRANSPARENT` Format. I'd like to know if there is some way for setting up this standalone, because If I add to obsever the whole code, it ends up into creating infinite `Layouts`, and overlaying them. Another useful thing would be how to destroy mLayoutParams before creating a new One.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easily fixed.
I just replaced

```
 mOpacity != 100 ? PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT : PixelFormat.RGB_565
```

by only

```
  PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
```

Then, When I wanted to set 100% Opacity, I just sent a hex value that equals to 100 :)